# Does anyone know of any analysis books that range from the introduction to undergraduate analysis to graduate real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, book-recommendation

And that are suitable for self-study. I have already been recommended Analysis by Lieb and Loss, would it work? I want to understand analysis well enough to pursue functional analysis and probability using measure theory. I have a degree in physics, I have basic knowledge of linear algebra and calculus in one and multiple variables.

Comment: Why are you searching for such a tome? What is the reason for not wanting separate books?

Comment: Pugh's book is pretty good and seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: I can recommend https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf for intro analysis.

Comment: This is also a very well done "intro to analysis". In fact, I highly recommend anything written by the author. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0486472205/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen For two reasons, firstly I need to learn the content quickly to follow the line of research that I intend to pursue in the near future and secondly due to the price of some books that I saw were half the salary I receive.

Comment: @CBBAM Does Pugh's book cover real analysis at the graduate level? I've heard of it, but I thought it was only up to undergraduate level.

Comment: *I thought it was only up to undergraduate level.* --- What is (advanced) undergraduate level and what is graduate level greatly varies with the country, the college/university, the person making the judgment, etc. You need to be more specific about what your background is (i.e. beginning assumptions of the text you want) and what level/topics you want to end with (i.e. some of the most advanced topics of the text you want).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks for the advice, I hadn't stopped to think about that detail.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the books published by Dover. They are cheap enough that you can get several for what most textbooks cost. I don't think you will necessarily save time by focusing on a single book.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Can you recommend any Dover books on analysis that are at graduate level? The ones I find generally don't cover topics like measure theory and other topics typical of a master's degree.

Comment: The book by Johnsonbaugh and Pfaffenberger is quite good. If your goal is measure-theoretic probability, I would recommend learning measure theory via probability though. That tends to be a lot more fun.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you very much for your help friend.

Answer (score 1):

Well, at first Real Analysis is not a short topic, so it will be well to use different books for different topics, but since your interest in One Book, I will recommend Mathematical Analysis by Apostol. In this book you will get touch of everything of undergraduate level Real Analysis and there are also some Advanced chapter like multi-dimensional Riemann integrals, Lebesgue Measure, multi-dimensional Lebesgue Measure etc. Thank you